# Weird Javascript Array Syncing Trick?

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, pointers

I found a weird JS behavior :

```
var myArray = [ [1] , [2] , [3] ];

var myArrayCopy = [];

myArrayCopy.push( myArray[1] );

alert( myArrayCopy ); // 2, as expected.

myArrayCopy[0][0] = 'foo';

alert( myArrayCopy ); // 'foo', as expected.

alert( myArray ); // 1, foo, 3  =  WTF ? :)
```

See the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lapinvert/g6z744rj/).

Note that this doesn't work if we push directly values instead of arrays.

To me, it looks like pushing arrays into an array, translates somehow as if we pushed only references to those arrays, rather than copies, (which is not the behavior one would expect, please correct if I'm wrong).

Can someone explain why ?

Comment: array are passed byRef, its not as if you're editing a ref, you are editing a ref. you can use .slice() to get a new container with the same values (a shallow copy)

Comment: @dandavis - You're comment is conceptually correct, but inaccurate. There's no such thing as *byRef* in JavaScript, but passing an object (which an array *is*) causes the effect you're describing.

Comment: without arguing over semantics, in js, it aligns with what's mutable/immutable: numbers, strings, booleans are immutable and thus passed by value whereas mutables, aka objects, are passed as object references. to be pedantic, objs are not technically passed by ref, it's a pointer to the ref that gets passed by value, but that's just confusing, and the effect is of passing "byRef"...

Comment: @dandavis No that's not true. Again, *ByRef* is VB. (It's similar to `void f(int &v);` in c++, and `void f(ref int v);` in c#), but this causes the reference of (address of) the variable used during the call to the function to be "passed in", and actually lets the function mutate that external variable. What JavaScript does is more like `void f(int v)` or `void f(obj *v)`, where in the 2nd function the address of an object is used and mutating the object is visible from outside.

Comment: I guess the OP is not actually interested in a flame about how js works under the hood and what it resembles. By looking at his problem, it looks that he is still scratching the surface of the language. :-)

Comment: VB? yikes! bad coincidence, i should have said "by reference". I'm not sure how useful your comments are to the OP, or what i said was untrue, but let's not get sidetracked further; you can "be right" if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aliasing.

You are putting in `myArrayCopy` a reference to an existent object (an array) that is contained in `myArray`. Because of that, when you modify that array, you are modifying the actual object referred from both the above mentioned arrays.

Please, note that when you pass around objects in JavaScript they are not copied, instead you are passing around a reference to an instance and modify it in the scope of the receiver will result in a modified object in the scope of the caller as well.
There are some noticeable exceptions to this rule (as an example primitive types for they are not objects, or strings for they actually copied on write, and so on), but let's concentrate on your problem.

Considering that an array is an object, it happens the same in the following example, but it is far clearer from my point of view:

```
var o = { "foo": " bar" };
myArray[0] = o;
myArrayCopy[0] = myArray[0];
o.foo = "nolongerbar";
```

What does it return `myArrayCopy[0].foo`? And what `myArray[0].foo`?

That's called aliasing in most of the OO languages, anyway it's a common error when you deal with objects' references.

**EDIT**

Oh, it is not a syncing trick in any case, it's usually the reason behind annoying bugs. :-)

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer. Especially for pointing out the term of "aliasing" !

Comment: You are welcome. That's a term widely used, even though it's not common to find it mentioned in discussions about JavaScript. I don't know why, maybe there exists a term that has the same mean, but I find that *aliasing* is the most meaningful (at least to me, of course).

Answer (score 2):

The value of `myArray[1]` is an array (`[2]`). When you push that into `myArrayCopy` in `myArrayCopy.push( myArray[1] );`, you push the array, not it's contents (`[2]` and not `2`).

When you later mutate this array (`myArrayCopy[0][0] = 'foo';`), it obviously has an effect everywhere this array is used.

Comment: I was aware of pushing an array and not it's content, my question was how is that "obvious" that when I change the value myArrayCopy[0][0] it has an effect on the first array as well ! But I think the other answers may have answered it : )

Comment: @lapin - It's the same array. That's what I tried to address in my answer: *you push the array, not it's contents* and *When you later mutate this array*. It's the same array all along.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, That is make sense action, because myArray[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9buJ.png) And myArrayCopy[0] has same memory address. You can check below debugging capture

[image]

After passing through line number 9, those has been changed at same time myArray and myArraycopy's value to 'foo'

Answer (score -2):

This is perfectly right.

Since arrays acts as an object, it stores the memory address
instead of storing the values itself.

```
var myArray = [ [1] , [2] , [3] ];
```

`myArray` will store the address of the Array created (say `addr-1`).

Since the elements of the array is itself an array, it will now have three addresses corresponding to array `[1]`, `[2]`, `[3]` say `addr-2`, `addr-3`, `addr-4` respectively.

so finally we have:

```
addr-1 = [addr-2,addr-3,addr-4]
```

---

```
var myArrayCopy = [];
```

This will store a new address say `addr-5 = []`:

```
myArrayCopy.push(myArray[1]);
```

since you pushed the first element of `myArray` to `myArrayCopy`. It will store the address `addr-3`. like this`addr-5 = [addr-3]`:

```
`alert( myArrayCopy ); // 2, as expected
```

So of course this works fine as `addr-3 = [2]`:

```
myArrayCopy[0][0] = 'foo';
```

here you are modifying the value of zeroth element of zeroth element of `myArrayCopy`, i.e you change the first element at `addr-3` to `foo`

```
alert( myArrayCopy ); // 'foo', as expected
```

So it works as well:

```
alert( myArray ); // 1, foo, 3
```

`myArray` now has `addr-1 = [addr-2, addr-3, addr-4]`, where `addr-2 = [1]`
, `addr-3 = ["foo"]` and `addr-4 = [3]`.

Comment: Does your answer look to you like it's formatted as it should? (Look around, it's ***very*** odd in the crowd)

Comment: i know its not, i was answering for the first time, so i was just playing around.